# Access Criteria IIF Statement Issue

Tags: ms-access, criteria, iif

I'm trying to qualify a field based on a date.  If the frequency of the data is supposed to be weekly, I want to select one specific weekend date.  If the frequency is monthly, I want the frequency to include the specific weekend date and all weeks thereafter.  However, my statement below returns a blank table when False ("Monthly").  I'm guessing there's some specific formatting I have to do to the >= but I'm drawing a blank.  Any suggestions?

=IIf([Frequency]="Weekly",[WK_end_Date],>=[WK_end_Date])

FYI... the false statement works correctly when I input only that specific criteria without the IIF statement.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *IIf* this way. Correct your *Where* clause like this:

```
Where 
    ([Frequency] = "Weekly" And [YourDateField] = [WK_end_Date]) 
    Or 
    ([Frequency] <> "Weekly" And [YourDateField] >= [WK_end_Date])
```